# How to enable back button in react native tabBar?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

[image]

I have made tabs using react-native-router-flux.
Now I need a back button on navigation bar.
Is that possible?
My code snippet is

```
<Scene key="XXX" tabs tabBarStyle={XXX} tabBarSelectedItemStyle={XXX}>
<Scene key="Home" ... />
<Scene key="Login" .../>
</Scene>
```

Comment: How are you getting to this screen? Where will the back button go? A little more information about your navigation route would be beneficial.

Comment: Same issue, I can't get this back button in my tab view

Comment: I am wondering if the previous action state would be saved.
In the Home page, if I click Login tab, it must to go Login page, then click back button then go to Home page again.
Is that possible?